# C# Консоль, Запретить ввод

Tags: c#, консоль

Есть консольное приложение, и обработчик нажатия кнопок. Но при нажатии на какую либо клавишу, выполняется и действие, и вводится символ на экран. Как это можно исправить?
код вызова обработки

```
 while (!isExitTime)
            {
                ChangeMenu(Console.ReadKey().Key);
            }
```

код метода обработки

```
private void ChangeMenu(ConsoleKey key)
        {
            switch (key)
            {
                case ConsoleKey.Tab:
                    currectButton.Draw();
                    if (currectMenu.GetNext())
                        currectButton = currectMenu.CurrectItem as Button;
                    else
                    {
                        currectMenu.GetNext();
                        currectButton = currectMenu.CurrectItem as Button;
                    }
                    currectButton.Draw(SelectColor);
                    break;
                case ConsoleKey.Enter: currectButton.OnEnter(); break;
                case ConsoleKey.Spacebar: Console.CursorLeft -= 1; break;
                default:
                    isNeedReDraw = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
```

[image: до нажатия]

[image: После нажатия]

Comment: то есть вы хотите, чтобы юзер как бы вводил что то в консоль, но при этом не вводил? )

Comment: мне нужно чтобы пользователь нажал на кнопку, но когда он нажимает на кнопку срабатывает и мой обработчик, и при этом выводится нажатый символ

Comment: если он у вас сейчас не выводится, но вы его считваете, значит ли это, что вы можете его напечатать в консоль сами?

Comment: в том то и дело, что мне не нужно чтобы символ выводился, мне нужно сделать так, чтобы сработал только мой обработчик

Comment: Метод [ReadKey(Boolean)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_ReadKey_System_Boolean_) имеет эту перегрузку.

Comment: да, помогло, благодарю, оставите ответ? Я галочкой помечу

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov неплохо, я совсем звбыл про это. Давайте ответом, плюсану )

Comment: Всегда "смущаюсь" такие элементарные сообщения публиковать как ответы. Но с другой стороны, движок сайта потом будет годами периодически поднимать вопросы без ответов.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод `Console.ReadKey` имеет перегрузку [ReadKey(Boolean)](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.console.readkey?view=netframework-4.8#System_Console_ReadKey_System_Boolean_). Используйте её с параметром `true`.